# Republish a scoped private npm module as public

Tags: javascript, npm

I accidentally published a scoped module as private `@user/module`. How to open it, or republish it to be public?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the module directory run `npm access public`. Done!

Note, this will work even if you're not a paying customer of the NPM Inc any more.